# How to render Vue Components over Html5-canvas

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-canvas, paperjs

I would like to use an htmlcanvas a canvas as the background of a webpage and then have various Vuejs components rendered on top of it.

I am sure the information is out there I just don't know what to search.

Comment: You can display arbitrary elements over a canvas by positioning them in CSS with `position: absolute`, have you tried that?

Comment: No I haven't tried that because I didn't know you could do that thank you!

Comment: What does arbitrary mean in this context?

Comment: I just mean any element – Vue or even an ordinary `<div>`. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can style any element using CSS with `position: absolute` to overlay the element on top of the canvas.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="overlay">
    This is displayed on top of the canvas
  </div>
</div>
```